# Arraylist solo con alumnos aprobados

Tags: java, poo, arraylist

Buenas tengo un ejercicio realizado en donde introduzco una serie de datos de alumnos y los guardo en un arraylist. Lo que quiero es guardar en otro arraylist solo los alumnos que su media de notas se mayor o igual que 5 pero no se como empezar

Aquí el código:

```
 public class Principal 
 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("EJERCICIO ARRAYLIST EN JAVA\n");

        Scanner tecla = new Scanner (System.in);
        ArrayList <Alumnos> ArrayListAlumnos = new ArrayList();
        Alumnos objAlumnos = new Alumnos();
        Fecha objFecha = new Fecha();


        //Introducimos datos
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            objAlumnos = new Alumnos();
            objFecha = new Fecha();
            int notas[] = new int [3];

            System.out.print("\nNumero de expediente del "+(i+1)+" alumno: ");
            objAlumnos.setNumeroExpediente(tecla.nextInt());
            tecla.nextLine();//Limpiar buffer
            System.out.print("Dni: ");
            objAlumnos.setDni(tecla.nextLine());
            System.out.print("Nombre y apellidos: ");
            objAlumnos.setNombre(tecla.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Introduca fecha de nacimiento");
            do{             
                System.out.print("Dia(1-31): ");
                objFecha.setDia(tecla.nextInt());                               
                System.out.print("Mes(1-12): ");
                objFecha.setMes(tecla.nextInt());
                System.out.print("Año(1980-1999): ");
                objFecha.setAnio(tecla.nextInt());
                if(objFecha.fechaCorrecta()==false)
                {
                    System.out.println("\nFecha de nacimento incorrecta, introduzca de nuevo");
                }
            }while(objFecha.fechaCorrecta()==false);            
            tecla.nextLine();//Limpiar buffer
            System.out.print("Curso: ");
            objAlumnos.setCurso(tecla.nextLine());
            System.out.println("\nIntroduzca notas correspondientes(1-10)");            
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
            {               
                int nota;
                do{
                    System.out.print("Nota "+(j+1)+" : ");
                    nota=tecla.nextInt();   
                    if(nota<1 || nota>10)
                    {
                        System.out.println("\nLa notas deben ir del 1 al 10, introduzca de nuevo");
                    }
                }while(nota<1 || nota>10);

                notas[j]=nota;
            }   

            System.out.println("La media de las notas es: " + calcularMedia(notas));
            objAlumnos.setNotas(notas);     
            objAlumnos.setFecha_nacimiento(objFecha);
            ArrayListAlumnos.add(objAlumnos);
         }

        //Visualizamos
        System.out.println("\n\nDATOS INTRODUCIDOS\n");
        for(int i=0;i<ArrayListAlumnos.size();i++)
        {
            objAlumnos = ArrayListAlumnos.get(i);
            System.out.println(ArrayListAlumnos.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static double calcularMedia(int[] notas)
    {
        double resultado = 0;

        for(int nota: notas)
        {
            resultado+=nota;
        }
        return resultado/notas.length;      
    }   
}
```

Otra posibilidad, que no requiere modificar tu código, solo un añadido, es que cuando has guardado todos los alumnos, recorras el arrayList y almacenes en otro que te crees sólo aquellos que cumplen tu criterio, esto lo puedes hacer por ejemplo creando un nuevo método que recibe como argumento un ArrayList, y lo recorre para hacer lo que requieres con los objetos alumnos de su interior.

Un saludo.

Comment: Una pequeña duda que tengo, tendría que hacer otra pregunta diferente pero por no copiar todo el código de nuevo... Como podría hacer mi propia excepción para controlar que las notas tengan el rango del 1 al 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas creando un ***ArrayList*** llamado "ArrayListAlumnos", donde guardas todos 
los alumnos:

```
ArrayList <Alumnos> ArrayListAlumnos = new ArrayList();
```

sólo debes crear otro para los aprobados:

```
ArrayList <Alumnos> ArrayListAlumnosAprob = new ArrayList();
```

En el bucle de introducción de datos, al final estas guardando el objeto 
alumno con sus datos en "ArrayListAlumnos":

```
ArrayListAlumnos.add( objAlumnos );
```

Tienes que hacer lo mismo con los aprobados, en el nuevo ***ArrayList***, pero dentro de un condicional:

```
if ( nota >= 5 ) {

    ArrayListAlumnosAprob.add( objAlumnos );    
}
```

y como nota, lo estas declarando dentro de un bucle, lo declaras fuera y antes,
para que sea visible el en momento de usarlo en el condicional:

```
System.out.println("\nIntroduzca notas correspondientes(1-10)"); 
int nota = 0; //Nueva declaración y le asigno un valor para evitar problemas
for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
{               
    //int nota; //antigua declaración (visibilidad solo en el bloque)
    do{
        System.out.print("Nota "+(j+1)+" : ");
        nota=tecla.nextInt();   
        if(nota<1 || nota>10)
        {
            System.out.println("\nLa notas deben ir del 1 al 10, introduzca de nuevo");
        }
    }while(nota<1 || nota>10);

    notas[j]=nota;
}
```

Comment: Muy bien, todo correcto muchas gracias amigo!!